# Neo4j data modeling for branching/merging graphs

Tags: neo4j, branching-and-merging

We are working on a system where users can define their own nodes and connections, and can query them with arbitrary queries.  A user can create a "branch" much like in SCM systems and later can merge back changes into the main graph.

Is it possible to create an efficient data model for that in Neo4j? What would be the best approach? Of course we don't want to duplicate all the graph data for every branch as we have several million nodes in the DB.

I have read Ian Robinson's excellent article on [Time-Based Versioned Graphs](http://iansrobinson.com/2014/05/13/time-based-versioned-graphs/) and Tom Zeppenfeldt's alternative approach with [Network versioning using relationnodes](http://jexp.github.io/graphgist/?40364ac2a52f57aa520a) but unfortunately they are solving a different problem.

I Would love to know what you guys think, any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your experience level is. Any insight into that would be helpful.

It would be my guess that this system would rely heavily on tags on the nodes. maybe come up with 5-20 node types that are very broad, including the names and a few key properties. Then you could allow the users to select from those base categories and create their own spin-offs by adding tags.

Say you had your basic categories of (:Thing{Name:"",Place:""}) and (:Object{Category:"",Count:4})

Your users would have a drop-down or something with "Thing" and "Object". They'd select "Thing" for instance, and type a new label (Say "Cool"), values for "Name" and "Place", and add any custom properties (IsAwesome:True).

So now you've got a new node (:Thing:Cool{Name:"Rock",Place:"Here",IsAwesome:True}) Which allows you to query by broad categories or a users created categories. Hopefully this would keep each broad category to a proportional fraction of your overall node count.

Not sure if this is exactly what you're asking for. Good luck!

Comment: We have been working on that system for over 4 years now in our startup, it is in use in production. It is based on SQL and we are evaluating Neo4j as a replacement for the next generation. So I know how to create nodes, connections, attributes, labels, etc. in Neo4j. 

It is a collaborative system and we want users to edit the graph in their own separate "branches" and merge back their changes to the main "branch" just like in Source Code Management systems. My question was about how should we model such "branches" in Neo4j?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. While this isn't insane, think about the type of system you're replacing first. SQL. In SQL databases you wouldn't use branches because it's data storage. If you're trying to get data from multiple sources into one DB, I'd suggest exporting them all to CSV files and using a MERGE statement in cypher to bring them all into your DB at once.

This could manifest similar to branching by having each person run a script on their own copy of the DB when you merge that takes all the nodes and edges in their copy and puts them all into a CSV. IE

```
MATCH (n)-[:e]-(n2)
RETURN n,e,n2
```

Then comparing these CSV's as you pull them into your final DB to see what's already there from the other copies.

```
IMPORT CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:\\YourFile.CSV" AS file
MERGE (N:Node{Property1:file.Property1, Property2:file.Property2})
MERGE (N2:Node{Property1:file.Property1, Property2:file.Property2})
MERGE (N)-[E:Edge]-(N2)
```

This will work, as long as you're using node types that you already know about and each person isn't creating new data structures that you don't know about until the merge.